# Тест собственной CMS системы

Tags: php, cms

Доброго вам времени суток Друзья! Продолжаю писать свою CMS систему, большая часть уже готова. Сейчас я хочу попросить вас посетить [главную страницу системы](http://t.pwon.pp.ua/laSearch/take_test/) и открыть по 3-4 раза каждую страницу сайта, запомнить время генерации каждой и отписаться здесь о результатах. Так же буду очень признателен, если вы зарегистрируетесь и по участвуете в опросе.

Спасибо!

Comment: Отклик, малая нагрузка.

Comment: А зачем было ссыль на w3c делать? ^.^

8 Errors, 9 warning(s)....

Comment: Я понимаю, там перед открытием хтмл главного тега выводится кол-во затраченной памяти, символы "and" не зашифрованы, это сначала для целостности хтмл кода было сделано.

Comment: дык я так и не асил что теститься то?
Вывод 42 строчного html'я чтоли?

Comment: Нет, мне интересно время генерации при некоторой нагрузке, в данный момент два моих друга безжалостно мучают главную страницу сайта.

Comment: Странно вы мыслите. Именно в таком режиме сайт и должен работать: отдавать закешированную статику через некий шаблонизатор и изредка генерировать индивидуальный контент.

Comment: Если для вас то что вы увидели называется сайт - тогда мне неочем даже спорить с вами.

Да и причем тут сайт, человек пишет CMS, ему нужно предусмотреть и написать туеву тучу вещей, предоставить API разработчикам для написания собственных модулей, API шаблонов, собственно шаблонизатор... И **многое-многое** другое.

Вот когда это будет написано тогда и будет толк тестить, да и тестить надо что-то конкретное а не хз что.

А этот тест, как по мне, больше похож на тест того с какой скоростью apache отдает html (т.к. сервер тут почти нифига не делает)

Comment: Давайте вперёд забегать не будем.

Comment: Так вперед забегаете вы а не я, тут до тестов еще "плыть и плыть"

Я вас пытаюсь пнуть в правильном направлении а именно - писать писать и еще раз писать... Вы же просто попусту тратите времени...

Да и по поводу исходников - чем раньше вы их выложите тем больше времени сэкономите... Хотя по этому тесту я понимаю что если вы и доведете все это дело до ума - будет это очень и очень нескоро...
(естественно при таком подходе - исходники не дам, тестю хз что хз зачем)

С уважением...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. http://t.pwon.pp.ua/laSearch/take_test/ (0.027)
2. http://t.pwon.pp.ua/laSearch/take_test/?module=users&page=login (0.008)
3. http://t.pwon.pp.ua/laSearch/take_test/?page=help (0.024)
4. http://t.pwon.pp.ua/laSearch/take_test/?page=home&module=show_page&id=1 (0.01)

Comment: Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

У меня на главную страницу вообще не зашёл.

Comment: Какая ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Слишком короткий Email || Пароль (Повторить) Это специально так задумано?

Солидарен с **AlexWindHope**!
Время генерации аналогично с **DemoS** - с погрешностью +- 0.005

А зачам это?

*?page=home&module=show_page*

Почему нельзя сделать дефолтный модуль который будет вызываться исключительно по index.php

И еще, две ссылки имеют вид:

- ?module=users&page=login
- ?page=home&module=show_page

Почему бы не сделать так?

- ?module=users&page=login
- ?module=show_page&page=home

В прочем у каждого свои таракашки в голове)

З.Ы. Тест CMS окончен)

Comment: Спасибо, первый тест окончен.

Comment: Я бы вообще везде сделал бы ЧПУ...

то что я сейчас вижу в url'e меня ни капли не вдохновляет...

Comment: Ну дык и ЧПУ проще собрать когда нужно обрабатывать только значение $1, $2 на основе того что я предложил!

А так если будет ?module и ?page то уже 2 руля нужно составлять. А к возможному концу написание системы их и десяток накопится!

Comment: Я же не оспаривал ваш пост а просто добавил...

 **no need to agr dude...**

Answer (score 1):

Время генерации страницы: от 0.008 до 0.016.
И выложите пожалуйста куда-нибудь исходники. Очень хочется на них посмотреть))

Comment: Толку от этого было бы намного больше

(правда думаю и Г в сторону ТСа тоже ^.^)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, на данный момент исходниками не делюсь, но в скором времени они будут доступны для скачивания.

Comment: Не в обиду сказано, но что-то мне подсказывает что там пока особо нечем делится ^.^

Comment: Модули есть, они не стабильны, не идеальны, не завершены. Опросы на сайте - один из плагинов.